# Android: Sharing to Google+ when Google+ app is not installed?

Tags: android, google-plus

I am working on a sharing feature where the user can share stuff on to social networks.
Particularly, when I share something to google plus, if G+ app is installed on my Android device, it shares perfectly. However, if G+ app is not installed, it doesn't show sharing option. It seems like if G+ app is not installed on my device, I should use webview so that sharing can be done in the webview. Is it possible to implement this way? I couldn't find the guide to making webview-based G+ sharing on Android(and token stuff). Is it even possible? or can one only share stuff to G+ when G+ app is installed on device?
Thanks in advance